# Reduce horizontal space between columns

Tags: groupplots

I'm using groupplot to generate the following graph:

[image]

**Regarding right graph:** If the space between the columns was reduced, then the graph would be more beautiful. Right now the columns are overlapping the graph's border, and there is plenty of space in between the columns.

**Question**: How can I reduce the horizontal space between the grouped columns in the right graph?

**Code**: See this [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/14681850jxrxqgxnwgqx#/56075731/) or see code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{pdflscape}
        \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
        \usepackage[landscape, a4paper, bottom=0cm, margin=0in, top=2cm]{geometry}
        \usepackage{pgfplots}

        \pagenumbering{gobble}
        \definecolor{customgreen}{RGB}{118,189,34}
        \definecolor{custompink}{RGB}{0,78,89}
        \definecolor{customlightblue}{RGB}{207,210,235}
        \definecolor{customlighterblue}{RGB}{232,234,245}
        \definecolor{custombrown}{RGB}{200,208,213}
        \usepgfplotslibrary{
          units, % Allows to enter the units nicely
          groupplots
        }

        \title{test}


        \begin{document}
        %\maketitle

        \hspace{2cm}{\Huge \color{customgreen} Medicin}
                            \pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
                                interval                    & a                             & b     \\
                                SABA                        & 85.00        & 64.20  \\
                                LABA                        & 65.00        & 8.20  \\
                                LAMA                        & 50.00        & 44.00  \\
                                LABA/LAMA                   & 0.00   & 13.30  \\
                                ICS                         & 75.00         & 24.30  \\
                                LABA/ICS                    & 30.00    & 76.70  \\
                                Systemisk glukokortikoid    & 0.00       & 3.30  \\
                                Fosfodiesterasehæmmer       & 0.00       & 0.30  \\
                                Methylxantin                & 0.00        & 0.40  \\
                                Hjemmeilt                   & 5.00   & 3.50  \\
                                }\mydata

                                \pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
                                interval                    & a                             & b     \\
                                LABA                        & 95.00        & 98.20  \\
                                LAMA                        & 50.00        & 57.30  \\
                                ISC                        & 105.00        & 101.00  \\
                                }\dobbetdata

                            \begin{figure}[h]
                            \vspace*{1.8cm}
                            \centering
                            \begin{tikzpicture}
                                \begin{groupplot}[
                                        group style={group size=2 by 1, horizontal sep=2cm},
                                        legend style={at={(0.5,1)}, text width=6em, text height=1.5ex, anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
                                        ybar,
                                        /tikz/bar width=.55cm,
                                        xtick=data,
                                        ymin=0, %ymax=130,
                                        ,height=10cm,
                                        nodes near coords,
                                        every node near coord/.append style={color=black, font=\footnotesize}
                                    ]

                            \nextgroupplot[
                               title=\textbf{Medicinering},
                               width=.65\textwidth,
                               xticklabel style={rotate=35, anchor=north east},
                               symbolic x coords={SABA,LABA,LAMA,LABA/LAMA,ICS,LABA/ICS,Systemisk glukokortikoid,Fosfodiesterasehæmmer,Methylxantin,Hjemmeilt},
                               ymax=100,
                               y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.05,.5)},anchor=south},
                               ylabel={Procent}
                            ]
                                    \addplot[red!50!customgreen,fill=customgreen!50!white] table[x=interval,y=a]{\mydata};
                                    \addplot[red!20!custompink,fill=custompink!80!white] table[x=interval,y=b]{\mydata};
                                    \legend{Klinik 30507, Landsdata}


                            \nextgroupplot[
                               title=\textbf{Dobbelt medicinering},
                               width=.30\textwidth,
                               xticklabel style={rotate=35, anchor=north east},
                               symbolic x coords={LABA,LAMA,ISC},
                               ymax=140,
                               y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.15,.5)},anchor=south},
                               ylabel={Procent}
                            ]
                                    \addplot[red!20!customgreen,fill=customgreen!80!white] table[x=interval,y=a]{\dobbetdata};
                                    \addplot[red!20!custompink,fill=custompink!80!white] table[x=interval,y=b]{\dobbetdata};
                                    \legend{Klinik 30507, Landsdata}

                            \end{groupplot}
                            \end{tikzpicture}
                            \end{figure}



        \end{document}
```